# with python selenium automatically filling captcha image number

Tags: python, image, selenium, numbers, captcha

I use selenium and I can fill name and password. how can I fill image number automatically with selenium? or is there any library to import for use this subject.

[image]

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from captcha_solver import CaptchaSolver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/yilmaz/Desktop/chromedriver")
browser.get("https://medeczane.sgk.gov.tr/eczane/login.jsp")
```

I can send_keys to name and password. I can fill "guvenlik anahtari" but I have no idea how reading captcha numbers? I install with pip captcha-solver, but I don't know how use?

Comment: Code trials and relevant HTML?

Comment: web site is https://medeczane.sgk.gov.tr/eczane/SayiUretenImageYeniServlet
code is:
**bold**
from selenium import webdriver
from captcha_solver import CaptchaSolver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/yilmaz/Desktop/chromedriver")
browser.get("https://medeczane.sgk.gov.tr/eczane/login.jsp")
**bold**
i can send_keys to name and password. i can fill "guvenlik anahtari" but i have no idea how reading captcha numbers? i install with pip captcha-solver but i don't know how use ? thank you

Comment: That's an image, you need to use image recognition libraries.